# Show available inventory on configurable product magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, inventory

I need on configurable product page to show available inventory of simple products,while selecting options, like price will change on option change in same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a way to show awailable QTY:

Override configurable.js:

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

Add :

```
jQuery('.myli').css('display','none');
 jQuery('#div'+config.allowedProducts).toggle();
```

In this function :

> _getSimpleProductId:

and paste this code in your PHTML

```
 <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
   if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);

    ?>
<ul><?php 
        foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {?>
            <li class="myli" id="div<?php echo $child->getId()?>" style="display:none;list-style:none">
            <?php 
            $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($child->getId());
            echo "We have ".round($productStockObj->getData('qty'))." items in stock!";
            ?>
            </li>

 <?php    }   ?>

 </ul> <?php }else{
     $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product->getId());
     echo "We have ".round($productStockObj->getData('qty'))." items in stock!";
     }?>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please share the layout XML. I am implementing the same for one of my projects.

Comment: No need to edit in layout.xml, Use above code in your phtml directly where you need to show

Comment: Ok thanks, in our project swatches are there so doing changes in configurable.js is not working. Do you know where to change if swatches are there?

Comment: Swatches should have their JS, Which will work on click on swatches, You have to check that JS and put above JS code there.

Comment: Use this answer for configurable swatches - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291072/show-available-inventory-configurable-products-magento-2/291091#291091

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will be changing StockStatus on the PDP when you selecting options(based on availability of the selected simple product):

> app/code/VVin/ConfigurableStock/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'VVin_ConfigurableStock/js/configurable-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/VVin/ConfigurableStock/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
], function ($, _) {
    'use strict';

    return function (configurable) {
        $.widget('mage.configurable', $['mage']['configurable'], {
            /**
             * Returns Simple product Id
             *  depending on current selected option.
             *
             * @private
             * @param {HTMLElement} element
             * @returns {String|undefined}
             */
            _getSimpleProductId: function (element) {
                var allOptions = element.config.options,
                    value = element.value,
                    config;

                config = _.filter(allOptions, function (option) {
                    return option.id === value;
                });
                config = _.first(config);

                $('.option-stock').css('display', 'none');
                if (config && config.allowedProducts) {
                    $('#stock-' + config.allowedProducts).toggle();
                }

                return _.isEmpty(config) ?
                    undefined :
                    _.first(config.allowedProducts);

            },
        });
        return $['mage']['configurable'];
    };
});
```

> app/code/VVin/ConfigurableStock/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.configurable">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VVin_ConfigurableStock::configurable-available.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/VVin/ConfigurableStock/view/frontend/templates/configurable-available.phtml

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct() ?>

<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product) as $child): ?>
            <li class="option-stock" id="stock-<?php echo $child->getId() ?>" style="display:none;list-style:none">
                <?php if ($child->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                    <div class="stock available" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Tested on Magento 2.3.3.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to magento 2 .3.3
I want to display the quantities of all my products (simple and configurable products) in the product listing and in the product detail and in the product quickview.
do you have a code to offer me?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Post this in the comment section or create new question.