# Show available inventory configurable products Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, inventory, stock-availability

I have got it working and its outputting the right information, but I do not get the toggle to work. Now I think thats because of the use of swatches. Hopefully someone here can help me out with that!

> ***Original answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208985/72996***

If I edit configurable.js the way I think needed its not working, but I can't find the output in the source either, so I think swatch-renderer.js is used, but then I don't know how and where to place it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution for configurable swatches

**Step1:** app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml

Use code as in original question

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);?>
        <ul><?php
            foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {?>
                <li class="myli" id="div<?php echo $child->getId()?>" style="display:none;list-style:none"><?php
                $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($child->getId());
                    echo "We have ".round($productStockObj->getData('qty'))." items in stock!";?>
                </li><?php    
            }?>

        </ul><?php 
    } else {
        $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product->getId());
        echo "We have ".round($productStockObj->getData('qty'))." items in stock!";
    }?>
```

**Step2:** app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

in `_EventListener` function add below code

```
jQuery('.myli').css('display','none');
jQuery('#div'+this.getProduct()).toggle();
```